# How to prove continuity of a function from a metric space to a discrete space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Given a metric space $X$ and a discrete space $Y$, let $f$ be a surjective function $f:X \rightarrow Y$.

What is the way to prove that $f$ is continuous? Since $Y$ is discrete, each set is clopen. Should I prove two things: that for every open set of $Y$, its pre-image in $X$ is open and that for every closed set in $Y$, its pre-image is closed?

Is there a case where the pre-image under $f$ of an open set in $Y$ is open in $X$, but the pre-image under $f$ of a closed set in $Y$ is not closed in $X$?

Comment: If the preimage of *all* open sets are open sets, then by complementary, the preimage of all closed sets will be closed.

Comment: The preimage of every set should be open (and closed). In special, the preimage of single values $f^{-1}(y)$ should be open (and closed). This is also sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

This is not always true. Consider the sign function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \{-1,0,1\}$, where $f(x)$ is the sign of $x$ ($-1$, $0$, or $1$, depending on whether $x$ is negative, zero, or positive). Can you graph this function? Does it look continuous for the usual Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}$?

However, if you are asking how you would prove this for a particular $f$ that might be continuous, one way is to show that the inverse image of every open set is open. Since every subset of $Y$ is open, then it would suffice to show that the inverse image of every subset $B$ of $Y$ is open. You could do this by showing that $f^{-1}(y)$ is open for each $y\in Y$, because $f^{-1}(B)$ is the union $\bigcup_{y\in B}f^{-1}(y)$, and the union of open sets is open.